# No overload for 'save_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:button `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="save_players" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="save_Click" />` which wants to run the following code, but gets an error "No overload for 'save_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'".

I recon this is because the method signature does not match EventHandler delegate - but I dont know how to fix it. Any help here please?
Here is my C# method:

```
protected void save_Click(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in ListViewAddPlayers.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            string tournyName = (string)(Session["TournyName"]);
            Label gameNumber = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblGame");
            TextBox txtPlayer1 = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtPlayer1");
            TextBox txtPlayer2 = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtPlayer2");

            string updateCommand = "//QUERY HERE//";
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
        }
    }

    Server.Transfer("tourney-standings.aspx?name=" + (string)(Session["TournyName"]));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be

`protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx

Comment: That worked, but now I have an error 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found.  PS - I am pulling data from a ListView textbox